# What 2 things did the man NOT eat for breakfast?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

A man awoke hungry, so hungry
He opened his fridge, so hungry
He ate all that was in it, so hungry
He went to the store, so hungry.

He bought all there was, and ate it,
Every type of food, he ate it;
Bacon eggs and fruit, he ate it,
Vegs, breads, and grains he ate it.

Still not full he continued to eat,
He ate snacks, and cakes, and pasta and meat;
He ate milk, and nuts, and so many chips;
Potatoes, seeds, and even some fish.

Still hungry, he hunted, and dreamed on a wish,
Ate all of the animals, and birds and the fish;
Then drank all the water, and ate all the plants.
He even ate rocks, and lava, and ants.

By the time he was done, he ate all that there was,
Ate the planets, the sun, and the moon just because;
He ate stars, and the void, and the black holes too,
Till he ate all the universe, through and through.

It was still morning, but he still wanted more;
He wanted two things, but couldn't explore;
The two things he wanted, he still could not eat;
Why couldn't he eat it, he wanted this treat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A nice little poem, thought the riddle itself is an old one.

> Lunch and Dinner

Comment: Thank you :) Yes, yes it is a classic ;) With a new twist ;)

Comment: What about rot13(nyy qnl yhapu?)

Comment: @YoutRied rot47(w6 8@E :E E9@F89)